# tyring to use Angular-Cli: getting this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular-cli

```
Cannot find module '/Users/dq212/node_modules/@schematics/angular/application'
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/dq212/node_modules/@schematics/angular/application'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:27:19)
    at new ExportStringRef (/usr/local/Cellar/angular-cli/1.4.6/libexec/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/export-ref.js:15:32)
    at NodeModulesEngineHost._resolveReferenceString (/usr/local/Cellar/angular-cli/1.4.6/libexec/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/node-module-engine-host.js:61:21)
    at NodeModulesEngineHost.createSchematicDescription (/usr/local/Cellar/angular-cli/1.4.6/libexec/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/file-system-engine-host-base.js:151:34)
    at SchematicEngine.createSchematic (/usr/local/Cellar/angular-cli/1.4.6/libexec/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/engine.js:82:40)
    at CollectionImpl.createSchematic (/usr/local/Cellar/angular-cli/1.4.6/libexec/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/engine/collection.js:11:29)
    at Object.getSchematic (/usr/local/Cellar/angular-cli/1.4.6/libexec/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/schematics.js:40:23)
    at Class.run (/usr/local/Cellar/angular-cli/1.4.6/libexec/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/schematic-get-options.js:12:40)
    at Class.beforeRun (/usr/local/Cellar/angular-cli/1.4.6/libexec/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/new.js:90:31)
```

I installed `nvm`, `node`, `angular-cli`, and `typescript`. When I try

```
ng new projectName
```

I get the above error.  I'm new to a lot of these tools, but I did put in a ton of time looking for this error, not getting anywhere. Any help is appreciated.

I'm on `Mac Sierra` 10.12.6

Comment: I think that mean you are most likely trying to create a new project in another project. So just try to exit out from this directory by using `cd ../` and then `ng new project`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using private `npm registry` and some of the libraries are blocked there.

you can see the npm registry by command `npm get registry` and it should give you `https://registry.npmjs.org/`

if you are getting something else, you can change that by `git config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` to set it to public.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed. Somehow must have copied over, a node_modules folder into my user folder and not in my project directory. Silly oversight, colossal waste of time to figure out. Lesson learned. Conflicting folder caused lots of other Strange errors. Thank you.
Lesson, before re-installing the world, go to step one first.

Comment: I am having the same issue, could you please clarify what you did to get it working? Thanks